# How do I make predictions from Lasso coefficients?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso

I am struggling to understand the implementation of lasso regularization (*LassoCV* in *sklearn*) and feature selection. First, I used cross-validation to determine value of alpha that minimizes the MSE. Second, using this alpha value, to determine the optimal coefficients (using *linear_model.lasso_path* in *sklearn*) and ordering of attributes for deployment. From here the book I'm using simply states that "these are the coefficients to deploy". In fact, looking for similar tutorials on the web, all examples appear to stop at this point with no further explanation of deployment/prediction making. How should I employ the coefficients to make predictions on either subsets of my data or on newly arriving data?

So, I call:

```
regressor = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False, normalize = True) 
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
#substitute new coefficients
regressor.coef_ = np.array(lasso_coeffs)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Is this correct way to implement?

Apologies for my confusion on this as I maybe seriously missing the point somewhere along the line and an explanation would be most appreciated.

Clive

Comment: The first step gave you a hyperparameter for your model.  The second step gave you your model.  So you have a model. You can now use your model to predict values for newly arriving data

Comment: Hi - I figured that. Just, everytime I try to use the model from the coefficients it seems worse than a basic model. I'm really asking for code to run predictions given the new coefficients.

Comment: Worse in what terms? Also notice that there is no guarantee that LASSO will be always better, so it may happen that it gives worse results.

Comment: Prediction errors are slightly greater

Comment: @user3329732 that might mean that you _do not need_ parameter shrinkage. Parameter shrinkage is a solution to a certain problem, so naturally it might not be useful if your data is good.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` use `sklearn.linear_model.Lasso`.
The `LinearRegression` model you use is not regularized (and Lasso is a regularized version of linear regression). The `Lasso` implementation has an parameter *alpha*:

```
regressor = Lasso(alpha= lasso_coeffs, fit_intercept=False, normalize=True)
```

In case I misunderstand your question and lasso_coeffs is not the alpha value, but all coefficients of a trained lasso model. Just use that model instead.

Edit: Giving this a second read it seems that your `lasso_coeffs` are the coefficients of a fitted `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV` model. In case you have run the `fit` method on `LassoCV` you can just use it's `predict` method and don't need to instatiate another model.